# xhci restart needed

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, kernel-modules, usb-device, modprobe

I have a laptop with usb 3.0 ports, ryzen processor, linux 5.14.3 kernel, and an external keyboard and mouse connected via a usb hub.

Occassionally, the usb devices stop functioning, both keyboard and mouse, as well as the internal keyboard. I've been able to look at dmesg tail using the linux virtual keyboard on mint, and saw this:

```
xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.3: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.3: USBSTS:\xff\xff\xff\xff%\xf6#f\xf0
xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.3: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.3: HC died; cleaning up
```

However, the problem does not rectify itself.
Instead, I've been rebooting but this time, in an attempt to fix it, I  found the kernel module called xhci_pci and rmmod it and then modprobe it and everything started working again.

```
rmmod xhci_pci
modprobe xhci_pci
```

Anyone know a permanent fix for this? Is this an issue with the 5.14 kernel or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about reloading the xhci_pci.

Comment: Yeah also having had severe troubles with my USB 3 controllers, thanks for the `rmmod` hint!